# Unlock Samsung S5(SM-G900W8) bootloader without rooting

Tags: rooting, samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-5, bootloader-lock

I am performing some tests on android devices, to properly do this I need to first unlock the device bootloader and run my tests on the device after which I then root the device and perform the tests again. I was able to unlock the bootloader for an HTC One m8 device using the offficial HTCDev instructions and then rooting by using TWRP Recovery and SuperSU. I need to replicate this process step by step for a Samsung Galaxy S5(SM-G900W8) device but I can't figure out how to unlock the bootloader for the device without rooting first. I have tried to follow the instructions [here](http://www.unlock-bootloaders.accountant/2017/04/samsung-galaxy-s6-6849.html) but it gets stuck in odin mode(step 7) and I have to do a battery pull. My question is how does one unlock the bootloader for this device nd then go about rooting it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike HTC, 1) most older non-AT&T/Verizon Samsung devices have their BL unlocked by default, and 2) Odin to Samsung is `fastboot` to others, just you can only access it with Odin/Heimdall on PC.

Just find suitable images (e.g. [TWRP](https://dl.twrp.me/klte/)) and flash away with Odin.